# Very odd behavior when returning a prototypical function from a module function

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'm writing some boilerplate for a new site and found myself with an interesting problem. I want to set up a module that returns an interface that can be extended. Using prototypical inheritance should make this an easy task, right? Even though I am returning a new instance of a function, it isn't extensible. I have a feeling this is a Monday morning mixup...

```
var someModule = someModule || (function($) {

  /*Initalize page*/
  init();

  /////////////////////
  // Public Methods //
  /////////////////////
  var api = function() {

  }
  api.prototype.example = function() {
    alert("hi!");
  }



  //////////////////////
  // Private Methods //
  //////////////////////

  function init() {
    ...
  }

  return new api();
})(jQuery);

someModule.prototype.newFunct = function()
{
...
}
//Causes an exception because someModule is actually an object, not a function

typeof(someModule); 
// "object"
```

Comment: `Even though I am returning a new instance of a function…` Constructors return plain Objects (by default), not Functions. See [step 1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2) of the internal `[[Construct]]` method that is called as the result of a [*NewExpression*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.2).

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, here's the way to get prototypical inheritance working with this design. The question really becomes, is this a good design in the first place?

```
var someModule = someModule || (function($) {

  /*Initalize page*/
  init();


  /////////////////////
  // Public Methods //
  /////////////////////
  var api = function()
  {
            ...
  }
  api.prototype.example = function() {
    alert("hi!");
  }


    //////////////////////
   // Private Methods //
  //////////////////////

  function init() {
    ...
  }

  var public = new api();
  return {
    extend: api.prototype,
    api:public
  }
})(jQuery);

someModule.extend.newFunction = function(){ 
   console.log('I'm altering the prototype!');
}
```

Comment: Why would you like to extend the object's prototype if there is only going to be one object instance? Prototype can be used to share members if you're creating many instances for performance or or inheritance patterns but your sample code doesn't show either.

Comment: Jquery follows a design with similarities like this. $.fn is really a link to its prototype chain. I was really looking to leverage prototypical inheritance along with a single module because I like being able to freely add things to the prototype, but like the privacy of the module. Contradictory? Yeah, I know it is.

Comment: jQuery returns many instances. $ or jQuery is a function returning instances so having members like 'find' and 'on' on it's prototype makes sense. `$(document).constructor===$` What your IIF returns is not a function and there will be no instances created with someModule.